# Queries on tree-like structure in mysql(hierarchical query)

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT ename,man,(SELECT SUM(t1.pop) 
FROM tree t1 START WITH t1.ename = t2.ename 
CONNECT BY t1.man = PRIOR t1.ename) population 
FROM tree t2 start with t2.man is null connect by prior t2.ename=t2.man;
```

The above code is an `oracle` query.

How do I perform hierarchical query like above in `mariaDB`?

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: 10.1.28-MariaDB